# Какой предлог правильно будет употребить стилистически

Tags: стилистика

Научный стаж **по** основному месту работы или научный стаж **на** основном месте работы?

Comment: Научный стаж, полученный на основном месте работы. Научный стаж, полученный по основному месту работы.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, верно будет *научный стаж **по основному месту работы*** , по крайней мере, во всех документах, мною встреченных, именно так, а вот понятие  "*научный стаж на основном месте работы"* я не встречала вообще.

Стаж (какой?) по основному месту работы (*исчисляемый по основному месту работы*), стаж (какой?) **по совместительству** (иногда бывает, что человек работал, помимо основного места, ещё и по совместительству, а потом с основного места уволился, а по совместительству продолжал работать по договору, тогда учитывается этот стаж, ведь с него тоже уплачиваются взносы)